# ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentencepiece while installing flair on python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, flair

While installing `flair`  using `pip install flair` in python 3.10 virtual environment on `mac-os` Ventura, I get the following error:

`ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentencepiece`

Seperately installing `sentencepeice` using `pip install sentenpeice` did not work.

Upgrading `pip` did not work.

I am using Intel macbook.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/issues/378#issuecomment-971881242) suggested by Github user [@millnerryan](https://github.com/millnerryan) is crisp and precise.

Comment: For M1 macbook, [this one](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/issues/378#issuecomment-969896519) worked for me.

Comment: Stumbled on the same issue while I was trying to pip install sentence-transformers on M1 mac mini. Followed your instructions and problem was resolved. Thank you @adeepak7

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading Python.

I was having this same issue, also with an intel mac, everytime I tried to use the transformers library, went through a lot of possible solutions without success, even with multiple chatGPT advices. I uninstalled python 3.11 and got back to the 3.9.13 version and the issue was gone! It seems there's some issue with wheels for latest python versions